# Switching signature to base classes not possible easily?

Tags: java, rmi, nosuchmethoderror

I have an RMI service which provides the following method:

```
ArrayList<T> save(ArrayList<T> saveList) throws RemoteException;
```

I want to change its signature to:

```
Collection<T> save(Collection<T> saveList) throws RemoteException;
```

This doesn't result in compile errors, so everything seems to be ok. But when the client application tries to execute that method I get the following exception. I haven't changed the callers which means the method gets still called with an `ArrayList`.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com/IDatabaseDao.sync(Ljava/util/ArrayList;)Ljava/util/ArrayList;
```

I don't know how RMI works in detail, but it seems that the method cannot be found because it doesn't have the expected String representation? Is that true? So I would have to change all callers here, or is there a better way?

This seems to be very error prone because I get no compile errors here. Is there a tool which recognizes such problems, maybe an Eclipse plug-in?

Answer (score 0):

the error message is clear: no such method found. this is because the method is not defined  by its name only, but also by parameters and return types. you've practically removed one method and created another.

you MUST change the caller here.

Answer (score 0):

What my understanding is that the below are different method declarations because of different parameter type:

```
ArrayList<T> save(ArrayList<T> saveList) throws RemoteException;
Collection<T> save(Collection<T> saveList) throws RemoteException;
```

Where you can try to put the two methods in one single class in Eclipse, the IDE would not give any compile errors, that can pretty show my point is true.

The Java RMI will only called the method remotely which must have same declaration with Client. They are not so intelligent to find it out what you are doing and then given a NoSuchMethodError.

Comment: There is no difference between the two lines of code you have posted, and the rest of it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Your last paragraph still makes no sense. Throwing a NoSuchMethodError is exactly what happens. I don't know why you are saying otherwise, but that's the meaning of what you have written, insofar as it means anything at all. Try again.

Comment: @user714965 It makes sense that a NoSuchMethodError is thrown, and it *is* thrown, and it is thrown *by Java Reflection,* as you will see from the stack trace, and the Javadoc for Class.getMethod(). Not by RMI.

Answer (score -2):

You've changed the server end without updating the client. You can't do that. You need to deploy the changed remote interface, and the stub if any, to the client, and recompile any affected client code and redeploy that as well.

Comment: @user714965 RMI has exactly the same intelligence as the Java compiler actually. The Java compiler won't cope with that change any more than RMI does. If you change the interface you have to redeploy it.

Comment: @user714965 I mis-spoke slightly. If you had recompiled the client code against the new interface, as I said above, it would have worked. When you executed the old client class with the new interface definition it didn't work. That's because you didn't compile it. It has nothing to do with RMI at all.

Comment: @user714965 In other words you have zero evidence for your belief, and you have the counter-evidence that your code doesn't work. You are attributing mysterious powers to RMI that it simply doesn't have. It relies on the compiler and Reflection. If you examine the stack trace you will see that for yourself.